# how is that link box called

Tags: html, hyperlink, mediawiki-extensions

Sometimes I see boxes in web pages that contain links in different font sizes. The most-often visited links are in bigger fontsize, the "less important" links are in smaller font size. I would call this box the "weighted size link box", but google does not understand this.

I want to have a mediawiki extension for this box, so can you tell me how this box is named?

Comment: It's called a "tag cloud", and it is a HORRIBLE design choice. Don't do it.

Comment: thanks, put it as answer and I will confirm that it is right. Why is it horrible?

Comment: The same reason carousels are horrible. A lot of programmers seem to think they are "cool", but they are a nightmare for a user.

Comment: maybe it helps http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8158/do-people-use-tag-clouds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed called a **Tag Cloud** in web design or simple a **Weighted List** in graphic design.
As mentionned above, avoid using them as they are often shown. they are unreadable.
Ask yourself if you've often found something in this cloud. It should be called a tag fog.

The worst I have seen is a tag cloud in 3d moving with the mouse.. that's just... useless..

Instead of using this, try some alternative, Like using opacity & boldness on tags and order them from most important to less important.. after all, we're all used to read **from Left to Right not from big to small**.

Comment: I partly disagree. The 3d tag cloud is indeed useless, but the normal 2d weighted list is pretty useful when you just want to see the most used tags. And you notice them easier bc the text is larger

Comment: I may have been a bit severe on this one, imho it is logic, but I think it is not as readable as a simple elegant tag list, like the one used on stackoverflow, and if I need to put some weight on it, I would use a color or opacity influence. I think Tag clouds are beautiful as background for graphic design where you put important words bigger than secondary words. But it should not be used as unique tag access.